# Which was the Wonder Woman and Spider-Man crossover comic book?

Tags: marvel, dc, spider-man, episode-identification, wonder-woman

I saw a page where Wonder Woman and Spider-Man were there together.
I thought it was fan-made, but it was an original comic book.

I've seen the Superman-Spiderman crossover, but when did that crossover happen ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're talking about Marvel Treasury Edition* #28 from 1981. In "Superman and Spider-Man" (a sequel to Superman vs. the Amazing Spider-Man) Superman and Spider-Man battle the Parasite and Dr. Doom, with the Hulk and Wonder Woman guest-starring.

[image: Superman and Spider-Man]

It's merely a guest role, but they do share some scenes together:
[image: Spider-Man and Wonder Woman]

*Marvel Treasury Edition is an American comic book series published by Marvel Comics from 1974 to 1981. It usually featured reprints of previously published stories but a few issues contained new material. The series was published in an oversized 10" x 14" tabloid (or "treasury") format and was launched with a collection of Spider-Man stories